# Jena not loading data from imported RDF Files

Tags: java, rdf, jena

I have an RDF file that I loaded in TopBraid, I also imported some RDF files from the web. Finally, I saved the base file and check its code to ensure it includes the import statements.

```
<owl:Ontology rdf:about="">
    <owl:imports rdf:resource="http://www.bbc.co.uk/nature/life/Bird"/>
    <owl:imports rdf:resource="http://www.bbc.co.uk/nature/life/Animal"/>
    <owl:imports rdf:resource="http://www.bbc.co.uk/nature/life/Chordate"/>
    <owl:imports rdf:resource="http://www.bbc.co.uk/nature/kingdom"/>
  </owl:Ontology>
```

So, thats file, When I'm executing the sparql below, I'm getting the results:

```
PREFIX wo:<http://purl.org/ontology/wo/>
SELECT *
WHERE {
    ?subject wo:kingdom ?object .
}
```

However, when I'm using the same file with Jena, I'm not getting any results, it seems that Jena is not considering the imports:

```
// Open the bloggers RDF graph from the filesystem
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("/home/noor/TBCMEWorkspace/bbc/index.rdf"));

        // Create an empty in-memory model and populate it from the graph
        Model model = ModelFactory.createMemModelMaker().createFreshModel();
        model.read(in,null); // null base URI, since model URIs are absolute
        in.close();

        // Create a new query
        String queryString = "PREFIX wo:<http://purl.org/ontology/wo/>" +
            " SELECT * " +
            " WHERE { " +
            " ?subject ?x ?object . " +
            " } ";

        Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
        // Execute the query and obtain results
        QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
        ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();

        // Output query results 
        ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);

        // Important - free up resources used running the query
        qe.close();
```

Is there any way of how to make Jena consider the imports??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ordinary Jena model will not load imported OWL models, but an [OntModel](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/index.html) will. The basic Jena model is designed to process RDF (i.e. including OWL, but other uses of RDF as well), while the `OntModel` from the ontology API is specifically designed for working with OWL and other ontologies.